# How can I change listbox selected item background and foreground?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate, textblock

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListboxBack}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="284"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="332"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="18,77,0,151"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource DataTemplate1}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</Style>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid Width="276" Height="36" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.069*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.931*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="recback" Padding="40,0,0,0" Text="{Binding [0], FallbackValue=Number}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1.899,0,-5.334,0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="13.333" Height="38.277" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Margin="3.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" Fill="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ListBoxStyle}" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="listBox1" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
```

I create `ListBox` with `DataTemplate`. `DataTemplate` contains a `Rectangle` and a `Textblock`. When I select item in `ListBox` I want to change `TextBlock` foreground and `Rectangle` background. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a similar to the following approach. This way you will override the default Brushes with the specified `x:Key` used of this ListBox Only. Perhaps you need additional or different `x:Key`s to override

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

By reading again your question i understand that perhaps you also need DataTriggers in your DataTemplate.
 You might also try something like this **Notice that Forground and BackGround should be set in the style not in TextBlock** for this code to work:

```
  <TextBlock x:Name="recback" Padding="40,0,0,0" Text="{Binding [0], FallbackValue=Number}" Width="Auto" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-1.899,0,-5.334,0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="13.333" Height="38.277"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
  </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understant your answer.I hope so you understant my question ?

Comment: i think i understood your question. just copy in your listbox the ListBox.Resources part with the colors that you want and check again if that suits you

Comment: woow thank you for your answer but also I want to change foreground.

Comment: Also If I use this code "listBox1.selectedindex = 0", selecteditem's background be Gray

Comment: could I ask you o one question?

Comment: go ahead. why ask if you can ask?

Comment: I want to change listboxselected item with buttonUP and buttonDown.Can I do this ?

Comment: not clear or obvious to me. Perhaps this should be another question

Comment: I want to change listboxselected item with Keyup and KeyDown.Do you understand ?

Comment: if you have set Listbox's `SelectionMode` to `Multiple` then in needs some effort if you have set it to `Single` then it should be the default behaviour as long as listbox has the focus